# How to perform apprequest using native dialogs

Tags: objective-c, facebook, apprequests

We are living confusing times were documentation from the past merges with documentation from the present.

I am trying to make an app request, I have FB SDK 3.1 and iOS6. 
I am checking code from the address:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

I can not make it work, takes my attention the next paragraph:

In your app delegate import the Facebook.h header file and replace the Facebook framework
"FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h" import declaration: #import "Facebook.h"

I don't have Facebook class anymore in my libraries.
Facebook class had to be initialized with app id, delegate, etc... I don't know how it is supposed to work now, specialy having FBSession in place.

My question is, how to make a modern apprequest? And... what is with the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the requests dialog with the previous API, it's not available for the current one.

Make sure you follow this step from the docs -

The headers can be found here ~Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders. Drag the whole DeprecatedHeaders folder and deselect the ''Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)'' option to add the headers as a reference.

Add those headers to your project and you'll have access to the Facebook class.